# SSL USB Key Authentication in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

I'm attempting to automate a website interaction that requires that a USB key be inserted, an alert box then asks you to verify, and after hitting okay it opens a local program that requires a pin be input to activate the key. I'm looking for a way to have the bot enter the pin into the external program. Is there a library that can automate this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a keyboard input library to take advantage of the fact that windows changes window focus to the security window that opens, so now it emulates keyboard input to press enter, enter the pin, and press enter again.